# Custom json response after creating user in Django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to django-rest-framework. I am searching for a solution but can't find my straight forward solution and got stuck. Help will be cordially accepted.

I am getting a .json response like this after creating `ScreenShotUser` model:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "amir",
    "age": "30"
}
```

But I want to get a .json output like below :

```
 {
   "success": "True",
   "message": "Successfully sent",
   "user": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "amir",
     "age": "30"
   }
 }
```

ScreenShotUser.py

```
class ScreenShotUser(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      age = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

ScreenShotUserSerializer.py

```
ScreenShotUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ScreenShotUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

UserViewSet.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ScreenShotUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I am using django restframework 3.3.2. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `ModelViewSet` returns the newly created serialized model in response to a `POST` request.

If you want **all** requests to have a different structure that the serialized model, check Niranj's solution. However, if you need a specific response structure for this request only, you will need to override your view's `.create()` method:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        # Define how would you like your response data to look like.
        response_data = {
            "success": "True",
            "message": "Successfully sent",
            "user": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried with this. but got error: "create() did not return an object instance."

Comment: Ya this worked for me al last. I was wrong. error for my mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to give metadata on how your our json response must be. Please check this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/ more information

Comment: I can't understand how can I implement this with my problem. could you please give me any example list?

Comment: wrong answer I think. That link talk about the "Options" request.

Answer (score 0):

Use data as dict. and now update it with your user data

```
data = {
   "success": "True",
   "message": "Successfully sent",
   #serializer.data or anything that return user data dict
   "user": serializer.data
}
```

Comment: Thaks. I tried but got error like  
 "create() did not return an object instance."